# condition number of sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to obtain the condition number of a scipy sparse matrix. The way I managed to do it so far is by converting the matrix to dense, and then obtaining the eigenvalues of it:

```
$ python
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 26 2016, 10:47:25) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from numpy import array
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import scipy.sparse as sparse
>>> I = array([0,3,1,0])
>>> J = array([0,3,1,2])
>>> V = array([4,5,7,9])
>>> A = sparse.coo_matrix((V,(I,J)),shape=(4,4))
>>> A = A.todense()
>>> eig = np.linalg.eig(A)
>>> eig = eig[0].real, np.array(eig[1].real)
>>> def split(array, cond):
...     return (array[cond], array[~cond])
... 
>>> eigv, zero = split(eig[0], eig[0]>1e-10)
>>> cond = max(eigv) / min(eigv)
>>> cond
1.75
```

As you may expect, this becomes unfeasible for large matrices. I was wondering how this is properly done in Python?

Comment: [Tried this?](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.cond.html)

Comment: No, but isn't that working also on numpy dense arrays?

Comment: Have you studied the sparse linear algebra documentation?

Comment: I think it is. Probably still faster than your method, at least worth a try.

Comment: [This](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs) might be something. You can specify to calculate only the largest/smallest eigenvalues (according to amgnitude).

Comment: @hpaulj I did search the documentation, and I couldn't find a single function that computes the condition number. It seems only the `scipy.sparse.linalg.lsmr` returns it, but I'm not interested in solving the system.

Comment: @Michael it is actually faster, but I'm still converting it to a dense array so it is not scalable either.

Comment: @Michael your last comment may be useful!

Comment: The question has been asked for sparse matrices in general. http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/15864. Apparently you can only estimate it, and even that can be expensive. https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_the_best_way_to_estimate_the_condition_number_of_a_sparse_matrix

Comment: Just to finalize this question, [this link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/arpack.html) solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

As Augusto Sisa mentions the condition number is defined as

cond(A):=||A||  ||A^{-1}||

but this is essential the ratio of the magnitude of the largest to the magnitude of the smallest (in magnitude) eigenvalue. So it makes more sense to get those to values using `scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs()` [Scipy reference manual](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs) and find out yourself.

```
import scipy.sparse
import scipy.sparse.linalg

ew1, ev = lg.eigsh(A, which='LM')
ew2, ev = lg.eigsh(K, sigma=1e-8)   #<--- takes a long time

ew1 = abs(ew1)
ew2 = abs(ew2)

condA = ew1.max()/ew2.min()
```

The `sigma` option is specified because the default options don't do a good job finding the smallest eigenvalues. This option computes the eigenvalues near sigma in shift-inverse mode. This step takes a long time. You can speed it up at the expense of accuracy by specifying `k=` and `ncv=` options to values smaller than the defaults. Eg `k=3` and `ncv=8`.  But you don't really know if you will get a good approximation of those eigenvalues like that. 
You will almost always improve the accuracy by using the k argument to compute more eigenvalues, but defaults should be accurate enough for most purposes. Test it yourself to see the difference for your matrix.

**In general** one uses sparse matrices because the dimensions of the matrix make storing all entries prohibitive. If the data storage is prohibitive for the given dimensions, then for general matrices, much worse is the computation of the inverse. The computation of the inverse is itself prohibitive, but a sparse matrix does not generally have a sparse inverse so your stuck again with the first problem.

Answer (score 2):

As you mention, convert a sparse matrix to dense matrix is not usually a good idea for large problems. So, you shouldn't use functions like `numpy.linalg.cond()` function that is useful for dense problems.

cond = || A || * || A^-1 ||

Although maybe it is not the more efficient way, you can use functions `norm`and `inverse` in sparse module of `scipy.sparse` to evaluate the condition number (Invert a matrix is a computationally expensive process):

```
norm_A = scipy.sparse.linalg.norm(A)
norm_invA = scipy.sparse.linalg.norm(scipy.sparse.linalg.inv(A))
cond = norm_A*norm_invA
```

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sparse

n = 7
diagonals = np.array([[1, -4, 6, -4, 1]]).repeat(n, axis=0).transpose()
offsets = np.array([-2, -1, 0, 1, 2])
S = sparse.dia_matrix((diagonals, offsets), shape=(n, n))
norm_S = sparse.linalg.norm(S, np.inf)
norm_invS = sparse.linalg.norm(sparse.linalg.inv(S), np.inf)
cond = norm_S*norm_invS
```