# Estimate the condition number of a matrix H

Tags: python

I would appreciate help with how to handle an error message in python while trying to use the built-in function `linalg.cond`.

I have a matrix H and would like to estimate the condition number of H in python, if I print H it looks like this:

```
Input: print(H)
Output:
  (0, 0)    0.009990391975478638
  (1, 0)    0.0009360219325538901
  (373, 0)  0.005768269884693624
  (746, 0)  0.001546147793908611
  (0, 1)    0.0009360219325538901
  (1, 1)    0.009990391975478638
  (2, 1)    0.0009360219325538901
  (373, 1)  0.005158144023338903
  (374, 1)  0.005768269884693624
  (746, 1)  0.009380266114123917
  (747, 1)  0.001546147793908611
  (1119, 1) 0.006378395746048346
  (1492, 1) 0.002156273655263332
  (1, 2)    0.0009360219325538901
  (2, 2)    0.009990391975478638
  (3, 2)    0.0009360219325538901
  (374, 2)  0.005158144023338903
  (375, 2)  0.005768269884693624
  (746, 2)  0.0003258960711991691
  (747, 2)  0.009380266114123917
  (748, 2)  0.001546147793908611
  (1119, 2) 0.004548018161984182
  (1120, 2) 0.006378395746048346
  (1492, 2) 0.008770140252769195
  (1493, 2) 0.002156273655263332
  : :
  (199553, 201044)  0.002156273655263332
  (199554, 201044)  0.008770140252769195
  (199926, 201044)  0.006378395746048346
  (199927, 201044)  0.004548018161984182
  (200298, 201044)  0.001546147793908611
  (200299, 201044)  0.009380266114123917
  (200300, 201044)  0.0003258960711991691
  (200671, 201044)  0.005768269884693624
  (200672, 201044)  0.005158144023338903
  (201043, 201044)  0.0009360219325538901
  (201044, 201044)  0.009990391975478638
  (201045, 201044)  0.0009360219325538901
  (199554, 201045)  0.002156273655263332
  (199927, 201045)  0.006378395746048346
  (200299, 201045)  0.001546147793908611
  (200300, 201045)  0.009380266114123917
  (200672, 201045)  0.005768269884693624
  (200673, 201045)  0.005158144023338903
  (201044, 201045)  0.0009360219325538901
  (201045, 201045)  0.009990391975478638
  (201046, 201045)  0.0009360219325538901
  (200300, 201046)  0.001546147793908611
  (200673, 201046)  0.005768269884693624
  (201045, 201046)  0.0009360219325538901
  (201046, 201046)  0.009990391975478638
```

I found that one should use `numpy.linalg.cond` to compute the condition number of a matrix so I did that and got the following error-messages:

```
Input: linalg.cond(H)
Output:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-92-410e9b7d5998>", line 1, in <module>
    linalg.cond(H)

  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in cond

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 1765, in cond
    s = svd(x, compute_uv=False)

  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in svd

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 1641, in svd
    _assert_stacked_2d(a)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 196, in _assert_stacked_2d
    raise LinAlgError('%d-dimensional array given. Array must be '

LinAlgError: 0-dimensional array given. Array must be at least two-dimensional
```

Why do this error messa occur? And is there any way to fix it? I tried adding the norm `'fro'`to see if that would have made any different but unfortunately it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Provided the error message, I assume that the input to the function was not the correct type. Numpy works with numpy arrays, which are not the same as python lists or tuples. While often the conversion between list, tuple and numpy.array is done implicitly, in your case the matrix is not of any list or tuple type. To numpy it therefore looks like a 0-dimensional array, aka a scalar value. Because from your question it is not clear, what type the matrix H has got, I cannot give you advise of how to convert H to a numpy array.

You should consider giving some more information about H as

- how was it created
- which type is it (maybe the printout of `type(H)`)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I checked the type and it is an scipy.sparse.csc matrix so I will try to do some research on how to find the condition number of a scipy.sparse.csc matrix.

Comment: You could convert a sparse matrix to a numpy array using H.toarray() but I am afraid, that the matrix is too large to be converted into an array. That is probably the reason why it is saved as sparse array in the first place. Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43281468/condition-number-of-sparse-matrix

Comment: Thank you Jakob! I will look into that site and try it on my code!